# Rails - environment variables becoming undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Do environment variables in Rails expire?

I have been experimenting with uploading images from a Rails app to an AWS S3 bucket, and I was using this tutorial as a guide - https://www.codefellows.org/blog/tutorial-how-to-upload-files-using-the-aws-sdk-gem

The first time I went through and followed all of the instructions to build the basic template, but when I tried my first submission, I got an error that the environment variables related to my bucket and authentication were not found.  I must admit that I don't yet understand environment variables very well, but I had followed the instructions in the tutorial, setting those variables like so:

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=INSERT_YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID_HERE
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=INSERT_YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE
$ export S3_BUCKET=INSERT_YOUR_BUCKET_NAME
```

On a whim, I stopped the server, ran these commands again, restarted the server, and BINGO!  It worked.  I figured that I must have done something wrong the first time.

However, I was doing some more work on the template later on, putting together my own template for allowing multiple file uploads.  When I got my code in order and tried the first submission, I got the same error about the undefined environment variables.  Again, I re-ran the commands above, and then everything worked just fine.

Is there a systemic reason that this is happening, or am I making a mistake?  And how can I avoid having to constantly reset these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this : http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html

I'll sugger you the third option, create a `local_env.yml`file to store your environment variables so you don't have to rerun the commands again and again !